# IfError + vlookup VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following VBA code to test an integer variable.

`primerRescateCP = WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.VLookup("RescateCartera Propia", Range("B:B"), 1, 0), Columns(2), 0), 0)`

If the test is true the code runs well, but if it is false I get an "Application-defined or object-defined error" message and do not assing 0 to the variable.

I think the iferror formula is well written, so I can't find the solution.

Any advice should be appreciated :-)
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can't use `WorksheetFunction.IfError` like this because `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` returns a VBA error when it fails, not a `#N/A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on it. I gave @Gary's Student a full 20 minutes to get his act together ;-)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim primerRescateCP As Long

    'Initialize the result to whatever it should be in case of error.
    primerRescateCP = 0

    'Attempt to get the actual value.
    'If the attempt fails, it will be on the right hand side, before the assignment,
    'leaving the variable untouched.
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        On Error Resume Next
        primerRescateCP = .Match(.VLookup("RescateCartera Propia", Range("B:B"), 1, 0), Columns(2), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Display the result.
    MsgBox primerRescateCP
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks both suggestions! Really appreciated

Comment: @Diego, don't forget to mark the best answer using the big green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `IfError()` that way in VBA, consider:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    Dim primerRescateCP As Long

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        On Error Resume Next
            primerRescateCP = .Match(.VLookup("RescateCartera Propia", Range("B:B"), 1, 0), Columns(2), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            primerRescateCP = 0
            Err.Number = 0
        End If
        MsgBox primerRescateCP
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

An update based on the comments:

```
Sub poiuyt_2()
    Dim primerRescateCP As Long

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        primerRescateCP = 0
        On Error Resume Next
            primerRescateCP = .Match(.VLookup("RescateCartera Propia", Range("B:B"), 1, 0), Columns(2), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox primerRescateCP
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You have to check for Err.Number before the next `On Error GoTo`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using `On Error` statements, you can test for the error yourself:

```
Dim resultVLookup As Variant
Dim resultMatch As Variant
Dim primerRescateCP As Variant
primerRescateCP = 0
resultVLookup = Application.VLookup("RescateCartera Propia", Range("B:B"), 1, 0)
If Not IsError(resultVLookup) Then
    resultMatch = Application.Match(resultVLookup, Columns(2), 0)
    If Not IsError(resultMatch) Then
        primerRescateCP = resultMatch
    End If
End If
```